# How to measure the delay of sending coordinates over a socket?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sockets, tcp, ping

I have written code in C++ which takes the x and y coordinates of a robot and sends them across a socket using a little endian. The x and y coordinates are then received on the client end of the socket where they are used to control an actor in a game. All of my code works well but I would like to analyse how efficiently the coordinates are sent and received and to do this i would like to measure the delay in the sending of the coordinates.

I looked into this and saw that getting the time that the coordinate was sent and received and then calculating the difference was the way most people spoke about doing this. However, i am just confused how i would do this in my code as i have measured the time for the program to start up the robot by using `int Start = Clock()` and `int End = Clock()` and then getting the difference. But i don't know if this would be the most effective or accurate way of measuring the delay across the socket. So, i was wondering if anybody could suggest a way in which i could do this using the code below. The server sends the coordinates, and the client receives the coordinates.

SERVER code:

```
#undef UNICODE
#include "pch.h"
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
// #pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")

//#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 8
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 5000
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"
//two structures for converting the x and y back into doubles/floats
union {
    float myFloatx;
    unsigned char myCharsx[sizeof(float)];
} testx;

union {
    float myFloaty;
    unsigned char myCharsy[sizeof(float)];
} testy;

double x;
double y;

int __cdecl main(void)
{
    int start = clock();
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;
    double x;
    double y;

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo* result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;
    int iSendResult;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
    //added (to send back bytes to client)----------------

    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    char sendvbuf[8];
    int sendvbuflen = 8;
    //---------------------------------------------

    //Creating instances of the classes -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Articares::Core::ArticaresComm instance;
    Articares::Core::HMANData instance2;
    Articares::Core::TargetParams instance3;

    //Connecting to HMan -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    instance.EstablishConnection("192.168.102.1", 3000);
    int end = clock();
    int time = end - start;
    std::cout << "time to connect = " << time << "\n";
    
    //Starting the exercise and setting the targets --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    instance.StartExercise(3);

    instance.SetTransitionTime(8000, 1, 0);

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    printf("listening\n");
    iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Accept a client socket
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    //sleep command added to stop the targets moving before the on game instructions have been read by the user
    Sleep(80);
    //Set target 1 with targetx = 10mm and targety = 10 mm, ‘StiffnessX’ = 100 N/m, ‘StiffnessY’ = 100 N/m, ‘target gain’ = 1, 
    //IF WISHING TO INCREASE THE RESISTANCE PLEASE INCREASE THE 4TH AND 5TH VALUES IN THE SetTarget() function:
    instance.SetTarget("1", "10", "10", "50", "50", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0");
    instance.SetTarget("2", "10", "50", "50", "50", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0");
    instance.SetTarget("3", "50", "10", "50", "50", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0");

    // No longer need server socket
    closesocket(ListenSocket);

    // Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
    do {
        while (recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, MSG_PEEK) < 8) { ; }
        iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        //std::cout << " hello" << recvbuf << std::endl;
        if (iResult > 0) {

            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);


            // Echo the buffer back to the sender
            iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0);
            if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }
            printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);
        }
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closing...\n");
        else {
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

    } while (false);
    //Start:; allows the continual sending of coordinates to occur meaning that the program will not shutdown unless it is shutdown from the client end.
Start:;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        std::cout << i << "\n";
        Sleep(20);
        // Send an initial buffer
        double x = instance.hman_data.location_X;
        double y = instance.hman_data.location_Y;

        //following sends the doubles as char to the receiver
        testx.myFloatx = x;
        sendvbuf[0] = (int)testx.myCharsx[3];
        sendvbuf[1] = (int)testx.myCharsx[2];
        sendvbuf[2] = (int)testx.myCharsx[1];
        sendvbuf[3] = (int)testx.myCharsx[0];

        testy.myFloaty = y;
        sendvbuf[4] = (int)testy.myCharsy[3];
        sendvbuf[5] = (int)testy.myCharsy[2];
        sendvbuf[6] = (int)testy.myCharsy[1];
        sendvbuf[7] = (int)testy.myCharsy[0];
        

        //changed the length of the buffer sent as it was causing problems with sending coordinates. 
        iResult = send(ClientSocket, sendvbuf, 8, 0);
        std::cout << "X = " << x << " " << "Y = " << y << "\n";
        Sleep(200);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
    }
    
    goto Start;
    // shutdown the connection since we are done
    iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
        
    }
    // cleanup
   
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();
```

CLIENT code:

```
#include "Control.h"


#include "control.h"
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")
//#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 5000
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

#include "Components/StaticMeshComponent.h"

//Below the "unions" are called labels and these allow for the conversion of the bytes back to a numerical value i.e. coordinate

union {
    float myFloatx;
    unsigned char myCharsx[sizeof(float)];
} testx;

union {
    float myFloaty;
    unsigned char myCharsy[sizeof(float)];
} testy;


//Declaring global variables
SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

WSADATA wsaData;
SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
struct addrinfo* result = NULL,
    * ptr = NULL,
    hints;

char sendvbuf[8];
char recvbuf[8];
int iResult;
int iSendResult;
int recvbuflen = 8;
int sendvbuflen = 8;

double x;
double y;



// Sets default values
AControl::AControl()
{
    // Set this actor to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;
    //Creating an instance of the Root component and allows it to be seen in the editor and game for editing e.g. scale
    Root = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>(TEXT("Root"));
    RootComponent = Root;

    //Creating and assigning the static mesh component
    Mesh = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("Mesh"));
    //want to connect the static mesh with the root component so the pawn component can be edited in the editor
    Mesh->AttachTo(Root);
}


// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void AControl::BeginPlay()
{
    
    //////Below has the purpose of starting up the server: -----------------------------------------------

    wchar_t command[] = L"C:\\Users\\CCRT\\Documents\\UPDATED\\FINALSERVER\\FINALSERVER\\Debug\\FINALSERVER.exe";
    // Start the child process.

    STARTUPINFOW si{ sizeof(STARTUPINFOW) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    if (!CreateProcessW(NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        command,        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi)           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
        )
    {
        std::cout<< "CreateProcess failed\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Command success\n";
    }

    //Below makes the client repeatedly search for the server until it connects with it.
    int connected = 0;
    while (connected == 0)
    {

        // Initialize Winsock
        iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
        if (iResult != 0) {
            //printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
            std::cout << "WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n";
            //return 1;
            goto finish;
        }

        ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
        hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

        // Resolve the server address and port
        iResult = getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1\0", DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
        if (iResult != 0) {
            //printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
            std::cout << "getaddrinfo failed with error\n";
            WSACleanup();
            //return 1;
            goto finish;
        }

        // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
        for (ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {

            // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
            ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype,
                ptr->ai_protocol);
            if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
                //printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
                std::cout << "socket failed with error\n";
                WSACleanup();
                //return 1;
                goto finish;
            }

            // Connect to server.
            iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
            if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                closesocket(ConnectSocket);
                ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }
        freeaddrinfo(result);

        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            //printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
            std::cout << "Unable to connect to server!\n";
            WSACleanup();
        }
        else
        {
            connected = 1;
        }
    }
    iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendvbuf, (int)sendvbuflen, 0);

    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        //printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        std::cout << "send failed with error:\n";
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        //return 1;
        goto finish;
    }
    std::cout << "Bytes Sent " << iResult << " " << sendvbuf[1] << std::endl;

finish:;
    Super::BeginPlay();

}

// Called every frame
void AControl::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{


    // Following recieves the coordinates from the server:
    while (recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, MSG_PEEK) < 8) { ; }
    iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if (iResult > 0) {


        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);

        //the following turns the chars recieved back into the double format (uses the labels which were declared before)
        testx.myCharsx[0] = recvbuf[3];
        testx.myCharsx[1] = recvbuf[2];
        testx.myCharsx[2] = recvbuf[1];
        testx.myCharsx[3] = recvbuf[0];
        x = testx.myFloatx;

        testy.myCharsy[0] = recvbuf[7];
        testy.myCharsy[1] = recvbuf[6];
        testy.myCharsy[2] = recvbuf[5];
        testy.myCharsy[3] = recvbuf[4];
        y = testy.myFloaty;
        std::cout << std::endl;
       
        FVector NewLocation = GetActorLocation();
        FRotator NewRotation = GetActorRotation();
        // NewLocation.X = -y is corrct way round for the HMan to control the ball.
        //NewLocation.Y = -x
        //IF THE USER IS NEEDING MORE ASSISTANCE THE X AND Y COORDINATES CAN BE SCALED UP BELOW BY MULTIPLYING THEM BY A HIGHER VALUE:--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        NewLocation.X = -y *150000;
        NewLocation.Y = -x *150000;
        NewLocation.Z = 0;
        NewRotation.Roll = 0;
        NewRotation.Pitch = 0;
        NewRotation.Yaw = 0;
        SetActorLocationAndRotation(NewLocation, NewRotation, true);
        //the true is added to stop the actor moving through walls. 
        printf("NEW Y: %f\n", NewLocation.Y);
        printf("NEW X: %f\n", NewLocation.X);


    }
    else if (iResult == 0)
        //printf("Connection closing...\n");
        std::cout << "Connection closing...\n";
    else {
        //printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        std::cout << "recv failed with error:\n";
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        //return 1;
        goto finish;
    }

finish:;

    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You might find that the time to send/receive is within the margin of error of the 2 computers clocks (2 computer's clocks may not be completely in sync).  In practice this is a hard problem to solve, and is usually done by round-tripping the data packet, measuring to time difference on the sending computer only and dividing my 2.

Comment: Have a oscilloscope hook to two computers. Let sender raises a pin before it send and receiver raises a pin when recv.

Comment: Note: Remember to always test with optimized release builds when measuring performance. Testing unoptimized debug builds (usually the compilers default) is pointless, since they *will* be slow.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. Sorry i should've stated that there is only one computer but i am sending the coordinates across a socket because there are two different programs required for the whole system to work. So, both programs are running on the same computer.

Comment: If just one computer, local time is one 
approach.

Comment: Hi @MinxinYu-MSFT, thanks for your response. So, getting the time at sending and receiving and then calculating the difference would be accurate enough?

Comment: Should be fine if it's just one computer.